# If $n\ge m$, then the number of $m$-cycles in $S_n$ is given by $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Show that if $n\ge m$, then the number of $m$-cycles in $S_n$ is given by
>
> $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m}.$$

**My doubt**

Suppose I wish to count the number of $m$-cycles. Then I will get $\binom n m$ ways of choosing such cycles. And the cycles which have the same representation must be divided so I will get $$\frac{\binom n m}{m}.$$

What am I doing wrong? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose we want to count the number of $3$-cycles in $S_5$. We start by choosing any $3$-element subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, say $\{1,3,4\}$. This doesn't uniquely determine a cycle though, since we could have:

- $(1,3,4) = (3,4,1) = (4,1,3)$
- $(1,4,3) = (4,3,1) = (3,1,4)$

---

To prevent overcounting due to cyclic permutations, we make the convention that the smallest number of the $m$-element subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ must come first in the cycle. This leaves us with $m - 1$ elements that can be permuted in any order, each of which will produce a distinct cycle. So we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{m} \cdot (m - 1)!
&= \frac{n!}{m!(n - m)!} \cdot (m - 1)! \\
&= \frac{n(n - 1)\cdots(n - m + 1)(n - m)!}{(n - m)!} \cdot \frac{(m - 1)!}{m(m - 1)!} \\
&= \frac{n(n - 1)\cdots(n - m + 1)}{m} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: why this $\binom n m$.$(m-1)!$. Kindly explain. I could understand the argument that you gave in words but in notation i am having a little confusion.@Adriano

Comment: The number of ways to permute the $m - 1$ elements (such that order matters) is:
$$
(m - 1)! = (m - 1)(m - 2) \cdots (1)
$$
This is because there are $m - 1$ ways to select the second element, $m - 2$ ways to select the third element, ..., and $1$ way to select the $m$th element.

Comment: then why u are multiplying with $\binom n m$@Adriano

Comment: This is the Fundamental Principle of Counting, or Rule of Product (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). We have broken down the problem into two subproblems, so our desired answer is the product of the number of ways to do each subproblem.

Comment: oh.. good.. thank you...@Adriano

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There are more than $\binom{n}{m}$ ways of choosing such cycles. Using $\binom{n}{m}$ implies that order is unimportant in choosing the elements of a cycle, which is not the case. Instead, you want to count the number of cycles by saying: there are $n$ possibilities for the first element, $n-1$ for the second, and so forth. *Then* you can divide by $m$ to remove the multiple representations for a given cycle.

Comment: definitely. thankyou so much@rogerl

Answer (score 0):

If we use permutation notation, we have $\frac{P(n,m)}{m}$ for the number of $m$-cycles in $S_n$. Also, I think the formula is valid for $n=m$, so the question should be edited to "if $n\ge m $".

Comment: Is there any proof in this answer or only a formula is given?